# Postgres count the same join by different values

Tags: postgresql, join, aggregate, self-join

I've been trying to create a query that counts the number of different types of events associated with each entry in another table

```
city                   job             job_events
id | name | state      id | city_id    id | job_id | type | info
```

Event type can be one of start, complete, failed, paused

A job can be paused multiple times, and can have a soft failure before a hard failure

I want to create a query that outputs the following:

```
city.id | number of jobs | num started jobs | num complete jobs | num failed jobs
```

I've tried

```sql
SELECT city.id, count(job.id) AS num_jobs, COUNT(started) AS started,
 COUNT(complete) AS complete, COUNT(failed) AS failed
FROM city 
LEFT OUTER JOIN job ON city.id = job.city_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN job_events AS started ON type = 'started'
   AND started.job_id = job.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN job_events AS complete ON type = 'complete'
   AND complete.job_id = job.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN job_events AS failed ON type = 'failed'
   AND info = 'hard' AND failed.job_id = job.id
WHERE city.state = 'NSW'
GROUP BY city.id;
```

That gave me way more results than there were jobs, then I tried

```sql
SELECT city_id, count(job.id) AS num_jobs, COUNT(started) AS started,
 COUNT(complete) AS complete, COUNT(failed) AS failed
FROM 
  (SELECT distinct (job.id) AS id, city.id AS "city_id"
   FROM job 
   JOIN city ON city.id = job.city_id
   WHERE city.state = 'NSW') AS jobs
LEFT OUTER JOIN
 (SELECT distinct job_id FROM job_events WHERE type = 'started') AS start 
 ON start.job_id = job.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
 (SELECT distinct job_id FROM job_events WHERE type = 'COMPLETE') AS complete
 ON complete.job_id = job.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN
 (SELECT distinct job_id FROM job_events WHERE type = 'failed' AND info = 'hard') 
  AS failed
  ON failed.job_id = job.id
GROUP BY city_id;
```

but likewise the results don't seem to match up.

Obviously, I'd appreciate a pointer on what to do to fix this, but also if I can get some help understanding what I've got conceptually wrong here in trying to build this query.

Comment: Could you provide your table structures in the form of DDL (`CREATE TABLE blah (...)`) and some sample data in the form of DML (`INSERT INTO blah VALUES (...)`) and your desired result. Maybe a small job_events type table might be useful for enforcing data integrity?

Comment: "but likewise the results don't seem to match up." This is a bit vague.  Can you describe how it differed from what you want?  Or provide example input, and example desired output?

Comment: Are you looking for `count(*) filter (where ...)`?